# Is there a way to determine if a terminal is focused without asking the window manager?

Tags: terminal, xterm, terminal-emulator

I want to change some tmux styling when the terminal loses focus/becomes inactive (i.e. when I've clicked on an open Google Chrome window).  I know I could check with the window manager to see which application window is focused, but this doesn't work across window managers.

**Do terminal emulators themselves expose this information at all?**

I tried running `showkey -a` to see if any escape sequence was sent when focus was lost, and it doesn't look like it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480052/how-do-i-detect-whether-my-terminal-has-focus-in-the-gui-from-a-shell-script/606323#606323

Answer (score 1):

I think *some* terminals implement this, but not all, based on [this comment](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events/issues/1#issuecomment-104229978) on the issue tracker for the vim-tmux-focus-events plugin:

> About the question "I was expecting the event to fire when changing focus between different windows in my window manager": yea, I see how that would be very useful. I think this might be dependent on the terminal application you're using. I just tested this on OSX and here's some quick results:
>
> - it's *working* for iTerm when tmux is running inside the window
> - not working for iTerm running plain bash + vim inside (no tmux)
> - not working for Terminal.app (with or without tmux)
>
> [...]
>
> So, if I'm not wrong, it's up to terminal applications to implement "focus gained", "focus lost" functionality.

I have a vague memory (though I don't remember for sure) that focus gain/loss might have worked for me when using that plugin and gnome-terminal, so it might be worth a try.